# AngularJS $interval and REST Calls

Tags: angularjs

I've been struggling with getting $interval to work. So I was hoping everyone here could straighten me out. Here's my case..

I have a page, that contains a 'update' button. when that button is clicked it's calling a REST service to update a row in a table. On the backend we have a process that monitors that field and runs when it see's the value submitted. Once this process is done it changes the value to completed.

What I'm trying to do is once that button is clicked, a div will display with the status of 'Submitted'. then I want to use $interval to poll that field(via a REST call) and change my view once it's moved to a value of 'completed'. In short change the view from 'Submitted' to 'Completed'.

My problem is when the button is clicked, and I make my rest call if I set my 'data table' on the scope I get

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'clst_rfrstatus_data_table' of
>   undefined

If I change it up and declare the data table like so

```
var refreshStatus_data_table = StatusService.getRefreshStatus().get({cluster: $stateParams.cluster});
 refreshStatus_data_table.$promise.then(function (data) {
            for (var x = 0; x < data.message.length; x++) {
                $scope.refresh_status = (data.message[x].status == "null") ? data.message[x].status = "" : data.message[x].status; 
                $scope.$digest;
            }
        });
    },3000);
..snip..
```

I get

> ConsoleAgent: TypeError: Cannot set property 'refresh_status' of
>   undefined

I'm not following if I am not in scope or what.. Any help is
appreciated.

Code:

**myapp-routes.js**

```
myAppconfig(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
'use strict';
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
.state('status_page', {
        url: '/status_page/:cluster',
        templateUrl: 'views/clusters/status_page.html',
        controller: 'StatusController'
    })
..snip..
```

**Controller**

```
clusterApp.controller('StatusController',['$scope','$interval','$state','$stateParams','StatusService', function ($scope, $interval, $state, $stateParams, StatusService) {
$scope.refresh_status = "";
$scope.ButtonClick = function ($scope) {
$scope.refreshStatus_data_table = StatusService.getRefreshStatus().get({cluster: $stateParams.cluster});
    $interval( function(){
        $scope.refreshStatus_data_table.$promise.then(function (data) {
            for (var x = 0; x < data.message.length; x++) {
                $scope.refresh_status = (data.message[x].status == "null") ? data.message[x].status = "" : data.message[x].status;

                $scope.$digest;
            }
        });
    },3000);
..snip..
} //end controller
```

**view**

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="ButtonClick()" />
      Status: {{refresh_status}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method header for ButtonClick expects you to pass in the $scope, but you are calling it without anything, so the local $scope variable is undefined in your method body. You shouldn't need to pass $scope though:

```
$scope.ButtonClick = function () {
...
}
```

Comment: interesting, I removed $scope from my buttonClick in my controller


`$scope.ButtonClick = function () {
..snip..
`

and it's working. I'm not sure what I did here.. Was my code thinking $scope was some empty object?

Comment: yeah, essentially the $scope variable in your ButtonClick method was different than your clope variable outside of the method. This has to do with variable scoping, basically, javascript was creating a local variable called $scope that was completely different than your global $scope and only available within your function call. Removing it from the method parameters takes away that local version so your function knows to use the global one.